# Are wounds (ones that are still bleeding) considered najis/defiling?

Tags: wudu, najis, human-body

Will they prevent one from doing proper wudu and salat?

Furthermore, are there pardon/dispensation concerning wounded body parts with bandage/gauze for us to leave them dry during wudu?

Someone had told me that, things that come out of ones body are considered najis. Is it true?

Answer (score -1):

not all things come out from the Human body are Najis, take for example saliva, mucus, sweat, tears.. However urine, pus, blood, stool, semen are all impurities..

If impurities come out of the human body the wudhu will break, if semen comes out of the body through sexual intercourse or wet dream then Ghusl will be wajib too.. If the wound is such that if water enters it will be harmful then it is ok to leave the wounded part dry, however if their is a bandage on it then you will have to wipe over the bandage with wet hands..

Comment: why was this marked down?